# Efficient way to determine in which time window the sample stays constant in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

consider the following data with 4 persons:

```
ID Date (DMY)
1  2014-12-30
2  2014-12-30
3  2014-12-30
4  2014-12-30
1  2014-12-31
2  2014-12-31
3  2015-01-01
1  2015-01-01
3  2015-01-02
1  2015-01-02
3  2015-01-03
1  2015-01-03
4  2015-01-03
```

Now what I would like to do is detecting changes in the group of ID's per day. Initially when I thought about it, it was a relatively easy problem, but it is extremely difficult, because:

- At 2014-12-30, we see that there are 4 persons.
- At 2014-12-31 it should also be 4 persons, because the person with ID=3 and ID=4 don't do a transaction, but we can detect their activity later in the data, meaning that they are still in the sample.
- At 2015-01-01 there are only 3 people, ID=1, ID=3, ID=4. ID=2 doesn't do anything anymore in the rest of the data.
- At 2015-01-02 there are 3 people.
- At 2015-01-03 there are still 3 people.

So I want the SQL to return the dates: 2014-12-30 to 2014-12-31, 2015-01-01 to 2015-01-03.

This is extremely difficult in my humble opinion and I have no idea how to solve this. Can TSQL even deal with these kind of issues?

Thanks!

Comment: what happens if in `2015-01-04` appears a new `ID`?, let's say `ID = 5`?

Comment: what mean `At 2014-12-31 it should also be 4 persons,` ?? because you say `we can detect their activity later in the data,` how you do that? I dont really understand the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your qeustions, so if there appears a new Id, suppose at 2015-01-04 we get a new ID, then the sample group changes, so we get a new window at 2015-01-04 to some date.

@JuanCarlosOropeza, there are still 4 persons in the sample, because at a later date we can see that ID=4 has some activity (so he / she is still in our sample) and ID=3 is also doing at a later date a transaction.

Comment: So each ID have an activity window Select MIN(date), MAX(date) ?? In this case {1,3,4} have {12-30; 01-03} and {2} have {12-30, 12-31}

Comment: Dear Juan, you are correct, each ID has an activity window indeed. The problem is aggregating that into a total activity window in which the ID's stay constant, in other words. If ID 9, 8, 7 have an activity window of 3 days, then in the fourth day if ID 7 stopped, a new aggregated activity window is active, because ID 7 is not active anymore and I am interested in those "aggregated activity windows".

Comment: To give an indication of the size of the data, it consist of about 4 million rows with about 30 000 unique ID's.

Comment: So you already have a solution for this but is too slow? If that is the case you should share it.

Comment: I don't think the problem are the rows or the ID. How long are the Activity window and how long are the date intervals?

Comment: Dear Juan, currently I do not have a working solution yet, but working on it. But it is a very hard problem and I was wondering whether it can be done and whether it can be done efficiently.

Comment: For your second question, the total interval to experiment is one month, but I would like to do this for one year.

Answer (score 0):

So, someone is in the data from their first appearance to the last.  Here is one method with cumulative sums: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8f839/1)

```
with persondates as (
      select id, min(date) as dte, 1 as inc
      from data
      group by id
      union all
      select id, dateadd(day, 1, max(date)) as dte, -1 as inc
      from data
      group by id
     )
select dte, min(cume) as actives
from (select dte, sum(inc) over (order by dte) as cume
      from persondates
     ) d
group by dte
order by dte;
```

Comment: I try to reproduce this query and got an error on `sum(inc) over (order by dte)`

Comment: Are you sure you are using SQL Server 2014?

Answer (score 0):

This work in SQL 2008 [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fba1c/3)
I can't tell you about efficiency with your data size, but shouldn't have any problem.

```
WITH dateGroup(gDate)
AS (
    -- SEE HOW MANY DIFFERENT DATES ARE THERE
    SELECT DISTINCT DATE
    FROM [dbo].[testData] 
), userActivity (id, dBegin, dEnd)
AS (
    -- SEE THE ACTIVITY WINDOW FOR EACH USER
    SELECT ID, MIN(DATE), MAX(DATE)
    FROM [dbo].[testData] 
    GROUP BY ID
), rangeDate ( gDate, users)
AS (
    -- SEE WHICH USERS ARE ACTIVE ON EACH DATE
    SELECT *
    FROM dateGroup as p OUTER APPLY 
        (SELECT STUFF(( SELECT ';' + CAST(a.id AS VARCHAR(10) )
           FROM userActivity AS a
          WHERE p.gDate BETWEEN a.dBegin AND a.dEnd
          ORDER BY a.id
            FOR XML PATH('') ), 1,1,'') AS users ) AS f
), activityWindow (users) 
AS (
    -- DETECT WHEN THE ACTIVE GROUP CHANGE
    SELECT distinct users
    FROM rangeDate
)
-- SEE THE RANGE FOR EACH GROUP.
SELECT *
FROM activityWindow as p OUTER APPLY 
        (SELECT STUFF(( SELECT ' ; ' + CAST(a.gDate AS VARCHAR(10) )
           FROM rangeDate AS a
           WHERE p.users = a.users    
        FOR XML PATH('') ), 1,1,'') AS activity_window ) AS f
```

Not only you have the date range. 
You have which user are active in that range. You can split by `;`
Also you see all days, so if no data during a SUNDAY you can see it.
If only want begin end, you do split by `;` and take first and last date.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with c as(
  select min(d) as d from t group by id
  union 
  select max(d) as d from t group by id),
u as(
  select * from c
  union all
  select dateadd(dd, 1, d) from c
  where d <> (select max(d) from c) and d <> (select min(d) from c)),
r as(select d, row_number() over(order by d) rn from u)
select r1.d, r2.d from r r1
join r r2 on r1.rn + 1 = r2.rn
where r2.rn % 2 = 0
```

If I am correct, the idea is to select peak dates, i.e. when someone is added or when it is last day of someone. It is done in first cte. The second cte fills peak dates with next dates of those peak dates. Third cte is just numbering the row for following joins to get intervals.

I am not completely sure if this is correct logic, but it works on provided test data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d7a6/6